# Connecting to MongoDB through mongosqld (BI Connector)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Having issues getting the Mongo BI Connector (mongosqld) working/configured ([link](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/reference/mongosqld/#bin.mongosqld))

I have it running on a amazon linux ec2 box.  I am able to connect via mongo to the mongo server, and I was able to generate the schema from the box with `mongodrdl`

But when I try to connect remotely through the connector I get the following error:

**connection accepted from 108.20.YYY.XXX:53793, but could not initialize: unable to connect to MongoDB: no servers available: server selection failed: context deadline exceeded**

I have tried a bunch of configurations, all give similar errors.  So for now I have simplified the execution to:

`mongosqld --schema=schema.drdl --addr=0.0.0.0:3307`

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-147 elt]$ mongosqld --schema=schema.drdl --addr=0.0.0.0:3307
2017-11-29T03:27:36.147+0000 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] mongosqld starting: version=v2.3.1 pid=24455 host=ip-10-0-0-147
2017-11-29T03:27:36.147+0000 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] git version: fa3535342a4c5abe36e3cc28a2ecf72864dfc6fe
2017-11-29T03:27:36.147+0000 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
2017-11-29T03:27:36.147+0000 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] options: {schema: {path: "schema.drdl"}, net: {bindIp: [0.0.0.0]}}
2017-11-29T03:27:36.147+0000 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for mongosqld.
2017-11-29T03:27:36.147+0000 I CONTROL    [initandlisten]
2017-11-29T03:27:36.159+0000 I NETWORK    [initandlisten] waiting for connections at [::]:3307
2017-11-29T03:27:36.159+0000 I NETWORK    [initandlisten] waiting for connections at /tmp/mysql.sock
2017-11-29T03:27:56.199+0000 E NETWORK    [initandlisten] connection accepted from 108.20.YYY.XXX:53793, but could not initialize: unable to connect to MongoDB: no servers available: server selection failed: context deadline exceeded
```

Note: I have this working end-to-end when all services are on the same machine.

Can anyone shed some light?!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you're able to connect to mongod via the mongo shell running on the same server as mongosqld? My guess is that either your EC2 security group is not allowing the connection or that your mongod bindIp setting is not allowing remote connections.

Comment: Actually, in the example you pasted, you're starting mongosqld without the `--mongo-uri` option, so it's going to default to using a localhost:27017 mongod. Are you certain that your mongod is actually running on that server?